# android application keeps building up memory and eventually crashes. how to examine the application

Tags: java, android, performance, android-studio, memory

Can anyone recommend to tools or approaches?

We have an android app that runs as a service, this service sends info to the server every second.  The problem is that the service takes up more and more  memory. After a day we get an out of memory exception. How would i find the cause of this?  What tools can i use?  I tried MAT memory analyzer, but it gives seemingly useless information, or atleast to my eyes. Are there any other tools i can use to see whats allocating so much memory?

Comment: Check: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_CruQY55HOk